# AngularJS: Best practice to pass data to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have following Service-Function, that will return data, which I want to display (notice, that the data can change any time):

```
myService.getData(); // Returns an array
```

I have to use a service, since I need this data in other controller/services too.

Now I am not sure, what the best practicse is, too display the data in a template. What I do, is:

**Example 1**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myService.getData()">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Its working fine, but is it best practice?

I also tried following:

**Example 2**

```
// In my controller:
$scope.data = myService.getData();

// In the template
<li ng-repeat="item in data"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

This does not work (on page load the data is get once into $scope.data. Any Updates are ignored). I guess I could use $watch (to watch myService.getData()). But I guess that´s slower.

What do you think? Can I call a service in a template (like example 1)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: A snippet of the `getData` method would be useful

Answer (score 0):

use this as a second example(best practice):

```
// In my controller:
$scope.service= myService

// In the template
<li ng-repeat="item in service.getData()"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, this is (already) exactly what I am using. I am just not sure if this is valid, or I have to use some different approach.

Comment: it is the best practice.you can use it without any doubt.

Comment: @MukundKumar What makes you think that this is best practice? What is `getData` makes AJAX request, and then it's going to be executed multiple times per digest cycle?

Comment: whenever any changes would be in myservice object,it will refect in $scope.service. so no need to put $watch and other stuff in code(which make code dirty).if you have any best way to do same thing then please suggest us.

Comment: getData(){return _data;} This is all. _data is filled once onLoad via Ajax, or on different User interactions.

Comment: There is anyway a watch expression behind a scene in both cases. In case of ngRepeat `getData()` is going to be executed twice (at least). If it's okay, then no problem use it. Just saying, that this approach is not the best, and can't be the best, because it's not always appropriate. If `getData` makes AJAX request, this pattern is not recommended.